# Timestamp of file in c++

Tags: c++, timestamp

i want to check a file to see if its been changed and if it is, then load it again.. for this, i started with the following code which is getting me nowhere...

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct stat st;
    int ierr = stat ("readme.txt", &st);
    if (ierr != 0) {
            cout << "error";
    }
    int date = st.st_mtime;
    while(1){
            int newdate = st.st_mtime;
            usleep(500000);
            if (newdate==date){
                    cout << "same file.. no change" << endl;
            }
            else if (newdate!=date){
                    cout << "file changed" << endl;
            }
    }
}
```

all the code does is print same file.. no change continuously.

Comment: `if (newdate==date){ ... } else if (newdate!=date){ ... }` I think that's because there is a third possibility here ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you're calling `stat()` outside the loop.

The result from stat() is correct *at that particular moment*. you need to call stat() again each time you want to check it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you `stat` before the loop. The info you obtain by your initial `stat` is never updated. Move the call to `stat` into the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux and writing specifically for that platform you can use inotify to inform you when a file changes rather than continually polling it.

See man inotify to see how to use.

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to move stat call in while loop.
your while loop should look like this

```
while(1){
    ierr = stat ("/Volumes/Backup/song.rtf", &st);
    int newdate = st.st_mtime;
    usleep(500000);
    if (newdate==date){
        cout << "same file.. no change" << endl;
    }
    else if (newdate!=date){
        cout << "file changed" << endl;
    }
}
```